# System variable not displayed in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, environment-variables

I am changing the Path variable under System variables in my Windows PC. In my Python script when I am doing print os.environ['PATH'], then the newly added path does not display. The path which I am adding for the application is: C:\Program Files\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3.

Do I need to eliminate the spaces between "Program" and "Files" while setting the system variable (and other spaces too between Xtensa and OCD and Daemon)?

Thanks,

Comment: Remember that spaces are usually indicated by "\ " rather than by " "

Comment: How do you launch your script? If from console window, have you opened it before the change to PATH or after? If before you mihgt want to open new one so that it reads PATH updated PATH variable

Comment: Environment variables are loaded upon program start, so if you want to see the changes, you have to restart your script.

Comment: I launched my script from console or command window. So, everytime I change the path variable, I need to close the command window and restart it to run the script?

Comment: You don’t need to restart the console window (unless you also want to access the variables there), but you need to restart your script, yes.

Comment: The environment variables working scope is only within the process. After you exit (exit the interactive mode of python), these environment will be disappear.

Comment: Either start a new cmd.exe process, or else alter `PATH` in the current cmd.exe before running your script (e.g. `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Tens...`). The environment of a process defaults to being inherited from its parent. The control panel app *should* update the environment in the Windows GUI shell, explorer.exe. So a new cmd shell started from Explorer will inherit the updated environment.

Comment: To signal a registry update to all top-level windows, the editor broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with `lParam` as `L"Environment"`. If you have a thread running a [window procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can handle the message by reloading or merging `PATH` from the registry. For the user the value is in `HKCU\Environment`. For the system it's in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.